# Why do i get the "index of" page? (Laravel Nova Web App)

Tags: laravel

I have uploaded a Laravel Nova project into bluehost and made the changes on the DB name, user, and password, and I assigned the domain to the directory but I'm still getting the (Index of/) page when I open the domain.

[image]

Comment: How have you uploaded this? Have you installed composer and hit composer install? What OS are you using?

Comment: I have uploaded it the classic way, i zipped the files and uploaded them in the bluhost uploader

Comment: Did you run the necessary Laravel commands?

Comment: You have not properly configured your webserver. Your server's document root should be pointed at the `public` folder within your Laravel app, not the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because your vhost is pointing to an incorrect directory.
Your apache/any web server should be pointing to /dir/your-project-name/public, however now its currently pointing to /dir/your-project-name (public is missed)

- If you have ssh option, edit your vhost to point to /your-project-name/public directory.
- If you don't have ssh option (most probably if you're in shared hosting you won't have access to), try renaming the public to public_html and see if that works.
- If that still doesn't work, you would need to change the app configuration. Please see [this answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5)